# Recursive PartialAllExcept

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a type alias that would recursively define a type with the following conditions:

1. Remove `id` property
2. Make all properties partial
3. Make one property required
4. If the property type also has `id`, remove that and make all properties partial (except for `name` if it exists)

For reference, this is the code:

```js
type IDType = string | number;

type Person = { id: IDType };

type PartialAllExcept<
  T, // extends Person,
  R extends keyof T | string = 'name'
> = Partial<Omit<T, 'id' | R>> & R extends keyof T
  ? {
      [K in R]: R extends keyof T
        ? T[R] extends Person
          ? PartialAllExcept<T[R]>
          : T[R]
        : any;
    }
  : {};

type Parent = Person & {
  name: string;
  single?: boolean;
};

type Child = Person & {
  parent?: Parent | IDType;
  name: string;
  adult: boolean;
};

const data: PartialAllExcept<Child, 'parent'> = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  parent: { name: 'John Doe Sr' },
  adult: true,
};
```

Despite the conditions, even if I were to hardcode the required property, say by doing

```js
type PartialAllExcept<
  T, // extends Person,
  R extends keyof T | string = 'name'
> = Partial<Omit<T, 'id' | R>> & R extends keyof T
  ? {
      [K in R]: { name: string };
    }
  : {};
```

That would still give me `Property 'id' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'Person'`.

A few more notes on what I've investigated so far:

1. Since `Child["parent"]` can be other values other than `Parent` (that extends `Person`) - `IDType | undefined`, just keeping it `Parent` helps this problem, but my app would require it to be `IDType | undefined` at places. Along with that, I get another error - `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type '{ parent: { name: string; }; }'` (more on this in the following points)
2. The generic `T` should extend `Person`, but for now is commented out - not a dealbreaker, but if that's included, then the recursive call gives - `Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'Person'`.
3. Since it's also a recursive call, and we wouldn't know what properties to make required (and others partial) for the property extending `Person`, the default `"name"` is given, however that would give - `Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof T'`. To suppress this, `R` has been extended by `string` whereas ideally it should be just `keyof T`. That's fine, however, when there is a case when the value of `R` is not a `keyof T` (say `name` property does not exist on `T`), then that required field shouldn't be added - therefore the empty `{}` at the end.

Comment: Does [this approach](//tsplay.dev/NBj4kN) meet your needs?  Your primary problem was that `T[R] extends Person` is not [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) across unions in `T[R]`. You want `Parent | string` to be broken into pieces like `Parent extends Person` (yes) and `string extends Person` (no). But you were checking `(Parent | string) extends Person` (no). There are more minor issues (how many times should you check `R extends keyof T`?) but that's the main one. If this makes sense I'll write up an answer.

Comment: I was checking for `R extends keyof T` twice because on keeping the single check OUTSIDE `{  [K in R]: any }` was raising warnings that I cannot access `T[R]` - but all your pointed problems make sense and is now working in all scenarios! Thank you, please submit as an answer so that I can accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not explicitly mentioned in your list of requirements, but if an object has a property of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `Parent | string`, you want that union to be broken into its constituent elements, transformed individually, and then reassembled into a new union.  That is, you want the operation to *distribute over unions*.  But your version of the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) doing that property mapping code does *not* distribute over unions:

```
T[R] extends Person ? PartialAllExcept<T[R]> : T[R]
```

If `T[R]` is `Parent | string`, then the compiler evaluates this type as a single cohesize unit.  Since `Parent | string` does not extend `Person` (if you had a value of type `Parent | string` you couldn't safely assign it to a variable of type `Person`), this conditional type evaluates to just `T[R]`, which is `Parent | string`.  So instead of the `Parent` part having optional properties, removed `id`, etc., it stays as-is and you get an error.

So that's the primary reason why it doesn't work.

---

If you have a conditional type and you want it to distribute across unions, you need to turn it into a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  In order for this to happen, the type you're checking (the `A` type in `A extends B ? C : D`) needs to be a single *type parameter*.  Since `T[R]` is not a type parameter, it's not distributive.  (`T` is a type parameter and `R` is a type parameter, but `T[R]` is a combination of type parameters.)

An easy way to fix this is to refactor the offending conditional type into its own generic type where the checked type is a plain type parameter:

```
type Refactored<X, R extends string> = 
  X extends Person ? PartialAllExcept<X, R> : X;
```

and then use it:

```
Refactored<T[R]>
```

Now `Refactored<Parent | string>` will distribute across `Parent | string`.  And you'll get `(Parent extends Person ? PartialAllExcept<Parent, R> : Parent) | (string extends Person ? PartialAllExcept<string, R> : string)` which evaluates to `PartialAllExcept<Parent, R> | string` as desired.

---

When I fix that (and some other minor things) I get the following type:

```
type PartialAllExcept<T extends Person, R extends string = 'name'> =
  Partial<Omit<T, 'id' | R>> & (R extends keyof T ?
    { [K in R]: MaybePartialAllExcept<T[K], R> } : unknown
  );

type MaybePartialAllExcept<T, R extends string> =
  T extends Person ? PartialAllExcept<T, R> : T;
```

And now things work exactly the way you want:

```
const data: PartialAllExcept<Child, 'parent'> = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  parent: { name: 'John Doe Sr' }, // okay
  adult: true,
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIgFXNAvFAzsATgSwHYDmUAPlHgK4C2ARhFgNwBQjokUACnegPZ5RoBvKDgAmALliJkUAL5MW09gEMswHEoA2AQQ0aAogA8AxhDDAAPAigQDwCHhHoOXXgBooAJWu37jjNnwiNAByPCVKCGCAPn5GKA4VNU1zAHlKHAsEd2DRYJJPKJiAMigACi8bOwcnAGsIEG4AMygrAH44+KghAG0AaWE+DwBdCQBZJRBaZVV1bV1DEzNLPqH3DxiZKAlyPBq8bgB3PA6ASnlWaHHJiGmkuf1jU0y17yq-TFxCGJQOq0rfJycLA8PitBIzTQ6B6LZ4FLYtc6KFT2YD8ZzA3hQEoCDphCISD6BJjxdCBDQQVoSajcbjkpR4JhyZgXKAAYQAFjgNCI0UCQViuh0wMi8MBKeCUfl4EhIMSyOEIASAoQ5UoROQNMAqTS6QzGEzGEZeJgoCIlMAlBJbrMoQsnuYOVyRNlhVgUdE0Tj4njFVBggApbjsvhwbiRVxCkVarry-F+wPBqCh6AAZSweRk7gA9FmoNwahMOmqNdHsOQIBGDUA)